# Different currencies for different store views?

Tags: multistore, currency

I'm creating a page that is multi-lingual in danish and english.
I've created two different store views because I want the shops to share categories, catalogs and of cause have different CMS pages.
I also want the two pages to show the prices in different currencies as well as you can check out in that currency.
How can this be done?

Comment: So I would manually have to write the price in both euros and danish krones? Can i still share products and catalogs? Or should I create these two times? There must also be some SEO aspect into this.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the default and allowed currencies per store view.

In terms of the system configuration of the Magento admin:

1. Go to the `System` > `Configuration` menu.
2. Go to the `General` > `Currency Setup` tab.
3. Switch to the [configuration scope](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#configuration/scope.html) corresponding to the store view for which you want to change the settings.
4. In the `Currency Options` group, change the values for `Default Display Currency` and/or `Allowed currencies` (after unchecking `Use websites`), and press `Save Config`.

Answer (score 1):

1. According to Magento default, you can easily set prices with different currencies for each store view:

For example, you set for English store view

Going to **System>Configuration> General> Currency Setup >Currency Option**. 
You choose English store view in **Configuration Scope** and choose a currency (Brishtish Pounds)  for this store view. Also choose Allowed currency for this store view.

Then Save config.

In the frontend of English store view, price is displayed with Brishtish Pounds currency and calculated by the formular: **Display price = Base price x Currency rate.**

2. However, although prices is displayed with Pounds in English store view but cannot checkout with Pounds because Magento only allows checking out with base currency of the whole website, not with display currency of each store view. 
   To do this one, you have to ask for an extension on Magento Connect like:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-currency-payment-checkout.html

I see that it can help to checkout with currency of store views which customers are selecting. 
If your customers are selecting English store view, they can checkout with Brishtish Pounds.

And this also can support any payment methods with multiple currencies.