# transalate Currency Symbol into arabic

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have two stores **English** and **Arabic**. I am using SAR(Saudi Riyal) currency symbol. Right now the price is shown like **SAR 1250** but for Arabic Store I want to translate SAR into ريـال and the price show like **699.00 ريـال**.

Comment: Try This Link It's May Be Help You.. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24047/currency-symbol-gets-lost-on-specific-store-view

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin Panel :
`System->Manage Currency->Symbols` Then Uncheck `Use Standard` Checkbox If Selected. Then Write `ريـال` **Instead** of `SAR`.

**Now** Click On `Save Currency Symbol`. And Refresh On **Frontend Side** to see Changes.

Comment: @Ahmar Arshad : Is Your Problem is Solved from my answer . If `yes` than you can accept my answer by the click on the "Right Sign" below my answer

Comment: now it is showing ريـال  for english store as well. I just want to show ريـال if the store is Arabic and SAR for english store.

Comment: for that You can follow : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31217/different-currencies-for-different-store-views       above link

Comment: In the above solution two different currencies are being used but I want to use only one currency which is **Riyal** and translate it into **Arabic** if the **Arabic** store is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following code from /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml

```
<numbers>
    <currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat type="standard">
                <pattern>¤#0.00</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
    </currencyFormats>

</numbers>
```

it will show " ر.س." as default currency symbol for Saudi riyal. To change it to "ريـال" open file /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar.xml and replace " ر.س." with "ريـال" at line 6223

don't forget to flush cache

Answer (score 0):

Since the US$ is given in the xml file and the other currency is taken from the admin panel, you are getting the error. You need to make the following changes in the ar.xml and the ar_SA.xml file. This changes fixed my issue.

In the lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar.xml file

You need to replace the US$ with the SAR

and remove the following code from the  lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml file.

¤#0.00

Clear the cache, Re-index and check your website.

Answer (score 0):

I am Changing UAE Currency symbol....

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
switch( $currency ) {
case 'AED'  : $currency_symbol = 'AED'; break;
}
return $currency_symbol;
}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please specify your problem in detail